# SQL get top level object from joins

Tags: sql, join, azure-sql-database

Working on a query right now where we want to understand which business is referring the most downstream orders for us.  I've put together a very basic table for demonstration purposes here with 4 businesses listed.  Bar and Donut were both ultimately referred by Foo and I want to be able to show Foo as a business has generated X number of orders.  Obviously getting the the single referral for Foo (from Bar) and Bar (from Donut) are simple joins.  But how do you go from Bar to get back to Foo?

I'll add that I've done some more googling this AM and found a few very similar questions about the top level parent and most of the responses suggest recursive CTE.  It's been awhile since I've dug deep into SQL stuff, but 8 years ago I know these were not overly popular.  Is there another way around this?  Perhaps better to just store that parent ID on the order table at the time of order?

```
+----+--------+--------------------+
| Id |  Name  | ReferralBusinessId |
+----+--------+--------------------+
|  1 | Foo    |                    |
|  2 | Bar    |                  1 |
|  3 | Donut  |                  2 |
|  4 | Coffee |                    |
+----+--------+--------------------+
```

[image]

Comment: with Postgresql you can use `WITH RECURSIVE... `

Comment: @RSolberg What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: @JasonTowne I'm pretty sure it is version 12 (SQL Azure)

Comment: @RSolberg Will the hierarchical query in my answer work to show the relationship path from `Donut` to `Foo`?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH RECURSIVE entity_hierarchy AS (
  SELECT id, name, parent FROM entities WHERE name = 'Donut'
UNION
  SELECT e.id, e.name, e.parent FROM entities e INNER JOIN entity_hierarchy eh on e.id = eh.parent
)
SELECT id, name, parent FROM entity_hierarchy;
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8cfca/2)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using SQL Server, you could use a query like the one below to generate a hierarchical Id path for a particular business.

```
 declare @tbl as table (Id int, Name varchar(30), ReferralBusinessId int)

  insert into @tbl (id, Name, ReferralBusinessId) values
  (1, 'Foo', null),
  (2, 'Bar', 1),
  (3, 'Donut', 2),
  (4, 'Coffee', null);

  ;WITH business AS (
        SELECT Id, Name, ReferralBusinessId 
        , 0 AS Level
        , CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(255)) AS Path
        FROM @tbl 
        
        UNION ALL

        SELECT R.Id, R.Name, R.ReferralBusinessId
        , Level + 1
        , CAST(Path + '.' + CAST(R.Id AS VARCHAR(255)) AS VARCHAR(255))
        FROM @tbl R
        INNER JOIN business b ON b.Id = R.ReferralBusinessId
    )

    SELECT * FROM business ORDER BY Path
```

[image]

Comment: I'll take a peak at this one later.